# Assign values to a grouped by dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

given this dataframe how can I find where if rows are grouped by first name and last name, the row with type as 'CA' get its Value column set to the row with type as 'GCA' value? so in this example the first row Alice, Johnson, CA, 25 will have its value changed from 25 to 40

```
data = {
    'First Name': ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob'],
    'Last Name': ['Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Jack'],
    'Type': ['CA', 'DA', 'FA', 'GCA', 'CA'],
    'Value': [25, 30, 35, 40, 50]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe like this

```
data = {
    'First Name': ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob'],
    'Last Name': ['Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Johnson', 'Jack'],
    'Type': ['CA', 'DA', 'FA', 'GCA', 'CA'],
    'Value': [25, 30, 35, 40, 50]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
updated_df = df.copy()

gca_values = updated_df[updated_df['Type'] == 'GCA'].set_index(['First Name', 'Last Name'])['Value']
updated_df.loc[df['Type'] == 'CA', 'Value'] = updated_df[updated_df['Type'] == 'CA'].apply(
    lambda row: gca_values.get((row['First Name'], row['Last Name']), row['Value']), axis=1)

updated_df
```

Answer (score 1):

one option to avoid apply is to unstack and stack:

```py
(df
.pivot(
    index = ['First Name', 'Last Name'], 
    columns='Type', 
    values='Value')
.assign(
    CA=lambda df: np.where(df.GCA.notna(), 
                           df.GCA, 
                           df.CA))
.stack()
.reset_index(name='Value')
)
  First Name Last Name Type  Value
0      Alice   Johnson   CA   40.0
1      Alice   Johnson   DA   30.0
2      Alice   Johnson   FA   35.0
3      Alice   Johnson  GCA   40.0
4        Bob      Jack   CA   50.0
```